# Selenium Alert behavior

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Which of the following statements is TRUE when an alert is open in a browser? (Assume that
driver is a WebDriver object)

I.  `driver.findElements` throws an exception
II.  `driver.close` throws an exception
III.    `driver.close` closes the current window.
IV. `driver.findElements` returns an empty list.

☐ (a) I, II.
☐ (b) I, III.
☐ (c) II, III.
☐ (d) III, IV.

My answer would be **D(III and IV)** as I know `driver.findElements` doesn't throws the exception and only returns the empty list when it doesn't able to find an element([https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/difference-between-findelement-and-findelements-methods/#:~:text=findElements%20method%20returns%20the%20list,t%20exist%20on%20the%20page.](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/difference-between-findelement-and-findelements-methods/#:%7E:text=findElements%20method%20returns%20the%20list,t%20exist%20on%20the%20page.))

Your thoughts please. i found the answer as  below

Answer B is correct
• In this case `driver.findElements` method would throw an exception, however
driver.close would close the window as expected. can someone explain this for me

```
driver.findElements
driver.close
```

Comment: Where did you find _Answer B is correct_?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium  This question was asked as part of Sample question in Selenium-United certification
Link: https://www.selenium-united.com/_files/ugd/b7b6d6_059588ef1d4743918d5fb14c5a42d5f3.pdf

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit **Option D** (*III* and *IV*) is the [correct answer](https://www.selenium-united.com/_files/ugd/b7b6d6_059588ef1d4743918d5fb14c5a42d5f3.pdf) as:

- [*`close()`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#close()) closes the current window, quitting the browser if it's the last window currently open.
- [*`findElements()`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By)) find all elements within the current page using the given `By` mechanism. This method will return as soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will return an empty list if the timeout is reached.

Comment: i have written an email to the certification company and would vote this after their confirmation